# Wix File element Source set to installed file

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer, gac, wix3

I am installing files to \MyApp. I want to add some of these files to GAC. How could i refer to the installed location in source attribute of the File element ( which has assembly set to .net) to acheive this?

EDIT >>>

Jus to clarify a couple of things.

using Wix 3 to generate the msi the dll being added is a .net dll

the above segment is within a separate dir & component

I want to add a new file element to add the file to GAC

Answer (score 0):

The WiX.chm is pretty clear. To add a File to the GAC use the Assembly attribute. In your case, you want File/@Attribute=".net".

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the wild and rash assumption that you are trying to install a .NET dll locally, as well as add it to the GAC.  Here are some blog posts that might help you accomplish this with WiX:

[Installing an assembly to the GAC and the local file system](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2005/06/24/432521.aspx)
[Additional info about installing an assembly to the GAC and the local file system](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2005/09/02/460278.aspx)